Iptables forwarding outbound packets to another port of LAN bridge
I just built a router running Debian with iptables, DHCP, radvd, etc. Let's for the simplicity say the router has 3 ports enp1s0 to enp3s0. I used enp1s0 as the WAN port and created a bridge br0 for the remaining 2 ports. enp2s0 connects to an AP and enp3s0 connects to another Debian server. The routing works, but with one caveat: every time a LAN device from enp2s0 visits an unfamiliar site (say, github.com), the router decides the packet should go to enp3s0. As a result the packets are dropped by the server and the source device gets a connection timeout. After a while the router would realize that connection should go outbound and start sending everything through enp1s0, and I can finally visit github.com from the LAN side. pinging github.com on the router itself is always okay.
Here're the relevant setup:
/etc/network/interfaces:
# The primary network interface (WAN)
allow-hotplug enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet dhcp
iface enp1s0 inet6 auto

# Define bridge interface
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  bridge_ports enp2s0 enp3s0
  address 192.168.0.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0

  up ip link set enp2s0 up
  up ip link set enp3s0 up
  up ip link set br0 up

Here are the relevant iptables FORWARD rules. I omitted all the firewall settings.
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp1s0 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o br0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

ip addr results on the router:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:b8:e0:02:f3:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 100.8.220.128/24 brd 100.8.220.255 scope global dynamic enp1s0
       valid_lft 7007sec preferred_lft 7007sec
    inet6 fe80::aab8:e0xx:xxxx:f3ec/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:b8:e0:02:f3:ed brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:b8:e0:02:f3:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 82:43:49:30:14:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.1/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global br0
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2600:4041:4498:4001::145d/64 scope global
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd90:ddd4:1234:5678::1/64 scope global
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:145d/64 scope link
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Running ipconfig on my Windows client which initiated the ping:
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2600:4041:4498:4001:ba3e:6f0f:d710:8f88
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fd90:ddd4:1234:5678:598c:aa78:aa2f:7b79
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2600:4041:4498:4001:35d4:a773:5940:424c
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : fd90:ddd4:1234:5678:35d4:a773:5940:424c
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::665b:fe6a:d8e9:c135%18
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.10
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:145d%18
                                       192.168.0.1

Runnint ip addr on the other server:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:83:34:bf:43:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.2/24 scope global enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2600:4041:4498:4001::4368/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr
       valid_lft 86389sec preferred_lft 14389sec
    inet6 fd90:ddd4:1234:5678::2/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7e83:34xx:xxxx:4368/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

And ip route results on the router:
default via 100.8.220.1 dev enp1s0
100.8.220.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 100.8.220.128
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-88815338f73d proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-02dc459045c1 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1
172.20.0.0/16 dev br-a15226942bd4 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1
172.21.0.0/16 dev br-7ffec0af396b proto kernel scope link src 172.21.0.1
192.168.0.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1
192.168.0.0/24 dev unifimacvlan proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.5
192.168.0.4 dev unifimacvlan scope link

The unifimacvlan interface is there to be able to reach the macvlan docker container (192.168.0.4) from host.
I set up log statements for all iptables chains. Here's what I got when I pinged github.com right after waking up:
May 19 06:24:16 router kernel: RAW PREROUTING: IN=br0 OUT= PHYSIN=enp2s0 MAC=xx:xx:xx:6b:72:ea SRC=192.168.0.123 DST=140.82.112.3 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=45696 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1000 SEQ=1
May 19 06:24:16 router kernel: MANGLE PREROUTING: IN=br0 OUT= PHYSIN=enp2s0 MAC=xx:xx:xx:6b:72:ea SRC=192.168.0.123 DST=140.82.112.3 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=45696 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1000 SEQ=1
May 19 06:24:16 router kernel: NAT PREROUTING: IN=br0 OUT= PHYSIN=enp2s0 MAC=xx:xx:xx:6b:72:ea SRC=192.168.0.123 DST=140.82.112.3 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=45696 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1000 SEQ=1
May 19 06:24:16 router kernel: MANGLE FORWARD: IN=br0 OUT=br0 PHYSIN=enp2s0 PHYSOUT=enp3s0 MAC=xx:xx:xx:6b:72:ea SRC=192.168.0.123 DST=140.82.112.3 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=45696 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1000 SEQ=1

And I can see the outgoing packets mistakenly sent to enp3s0 using tcpdump:
$ sudo tcpdump -i enp3s0 -vvvnn icmp
tcpdump: listening on enp3s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
16:06:45.536644 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 25306, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 60)
    192.168.0.123 > 140.82.112.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 1, length 40
16:06:50.362736 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 25307, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 60)
    192.168.0.123 > 140.82.112.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 2, length 40
    <two more misdirected ping requests>

And the NAT table:
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.0/16 ! -o br-02dc459045c1 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.0.0/16 ! -o br-a15226942bd4 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 ! -o br-88815338f73d -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.21.0.0/16 ! -o br-7ffec0af396b -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8850 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.2/32 -d 172.18.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8851 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.2/32 -d 172.18.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.2/32 -d 172.18.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i br-02dc459045c1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i br-a15226942bd4 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i br-88815338f73d -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i br-7ffec0af396b -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -d 127.0.0.1/32 ! -i br-88815338f73d -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8851 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.2:8851
-A DOCKER -d 127.0.0.1/32 ! -i br-02dc459045c1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8850 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:8850
-A DOCKER ! -i br-88815338f73d -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.2:53
-A DOCKER ! -i br-88815338f73d -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.2:53


What's the default route(s) on this router?

Can you show the tcpdump output of packets for external sites egressing on enp3s0? And the complete ip route output?

@TomYan Yan The default route is via enp1s0. I missed it when pasting the lines here. Post updated.

@larsks Updated

Could you re-run tcpdump with the -nn flag (to show addresses instead of hostnames)? And could you replace your output showing the nat table with the output of iptables -t nat -S? Using iptables -vnL hides information that is useful when trying to diagnose network issues.

@larsks Sure, I've updated the post

Actually, it sounds more like a misconfiguration on another Debian server, that is, it is also assigned with the IP 192.168.0.1.

@TomYan Why so? I checked the other server and it has the IP 192.168.0.2.

Well, I can't think of anything else with After a while the router would realize that connection should go outbound and start sending everything through enp1s0. Btw, do all MAC=<REDACTED> have the same value? And whose MAC is it?

I mean, I don't have much experience with rogue DHCP server, but it sounds less likely to be the case here.

On which system are you running the ping? And can we get the output of ip addr on all the hosts involved? I don't see anything in the data you've shown us so far that would cause the behavior you've observed. @TomYan's idea is the best I've seen so far. Instead of redacting the MAC addresses, maybe just obscure the first 3 octets or something.

@TomYan Yes all the packets show the MAC address of my Windows laptop.

@larsks I'm running ping on a Windows laptop. I've added the output of ip addr to the post. One more fact: running ip route get 114.82.114.3 on the router gives the correct default route (via enp1s0), so it seems ip route is not where the problem lies.

You may want to add -e when you tcpdump to see what the destination MAC is. (You'd want to capture at enp2s0 instead.) Also, consider capturing ARP messages to see if there's anything quirky going on. (For example, multiple replies with different "answers" for the same request.)

You may also check the ARP entries on the LAN host directly (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/arp).

Solved. The reason is not related to routing but ARP. I set up a macvlan in order to reach the unifi macvlan container on the same machine. Turns out that macvlan is messing with the network. The tcpdump destination MAC address points to the macvlan interface initially. Thank you @TomYan and larsks for guiding me through this!

You should write up the solution as an answer; other folks might run into the same situation and find this helpful.

For those who encountered the problem, turned out it wasn't the issue of iptables but of ARP. I configured another (MACVLAN) interface on the router under the same subnet. By default Linux sends arbitrary MAC addresses as ARP replies, so when a device requests the MAC address of br0, it will get two responses.
arping 192.168.0.1
ARPING 192.168.0.1 from 192.168.0.2 enp1s0
Unicast reply from 192.168.0.1 [82:43:xx:xx:xx:xx]  0.676ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.0.1 [62:BC:xx:xx:xx:xx]  0.699ms
^CSent 1 probes (1 broadcast(s))
Received 2 response(s)

Linux seems to be smart enough to use the correct MAC, but Windows and phones aren't, hence the weird behavior.
To solve the problem, set the following kernel flags:
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore = 1 (or 2)

These flags tell the kernel to reply the MAC address of only the corresponding interface and  subnet. You can read more about the flags here
